# Problems in lesson from angular-meteor.com

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I start to learn angular2 and meteor, from http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular2/3-way-data-binding

And in 3th lesson i have 2 error in console:

```
 refreshingclient/app.ts (18, 11): Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
 client/app.ts (20, 19): Cannot find name 'zone'.
```

when i added some documents to Mongo from command line, they not appear on page.

and my app.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2-meteor.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Parties} from 'collections/parties';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2-meteor';

@Component({
   selector: 'app'
})
@View({
   templateUrl: 'client/app.html',
   directives: [NgFor]
})
class Socially {
   parties: Array;
   constructor() {
      Tracker.autorun(zone.bind(() => {
        this.parties = Parties.find().fetch();
      }));
   }
}
bootstrap(Socially);
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the client/app.ts file, the instructions (http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular2/3-way-data-binding) show:

> ```
> class Socially {
>     parties: Mongo.Cursor;
>
>     constructor () {
>         this.parties = Parties.find();
>     }
> }
> ```

It should actually be:

```
class Socially {
    parties: Mongo.Cursor<Object>;

    constructor () {
        this.parties = Parties.find();
    }
}
```

Notice `<Object>` has been added after `Mongo.Cursor`.

If you go to Step 4, there is a link to download a zip file of the code (https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially/archive/step_03.zip).  You'll see in there that the code is correct.

Comment: OK, its work, but only when i added files in server folder: **main.ts** and **load_parties.ts**. In tutorial nothing about it, can you explain me why its that happend?

Comment: The tutorial is very clear about that.  Read the `Initializing Data on Server Side` section.  Also re-read the `Declare a Collection` section which describes how meteor handles the special folders named "client" and "server".  You can also get that info straight from the meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Comment: I understand what is purpose of this folder. But in tutorial(before section Initializing Data on Server Side ) is information that without these files app should work correctly, but it isn't. So my question is why this files must exist to correctly work apps

Answer (score 1):

kuka-
main.ts and load_parties.ts are there just to create data in your db if there is none. So if adding those files made it work, there must have been something wrong with the data you created from the command line. My guess is the data you added from the command line went to the wrong collection (i.e. Party vs party). You can check your collections and data by typing

```
meteor mongo
```

at the root of your project to get a mongo prompt. Then at the mongo prompt type

```
show collections
```

This will display all collections in your db. You should have one called 'parties'. Type the following to see the content.

```
db.parties.find().pretty()
```

Study the data to make sure all property names are identical. If you created a property call 'partyName' and your form is looking for 'name', nothing will show up.